# Выводить текст в JTextField из другого класса

Tags: java, netbeans

Делаю Java приложение в NetBeans. Нужно выводить определенные данные, получаемые по ходу работы программы, в поле `jTextArea`.

Есть главный класс A (с методом main), в котором с помощью визуального редактора созданы несколько кнопок и одно текстовое поле `jTextArea`. По нажатию на кнопку вызывается один из методов класса Б, который производит определенные действия, и по ходу работы дает несколько результатов в виде строк.

Нужно выводить эти результаты в jTextArea. Пробовал сделать так 
`A.jTextArea1.append("\nзначение");`

Но проблема в том, что значения в `jTextArea1` появляются только после того, как полностью завершаться ВСЕ действия в классе Б(и программа вернется в класс А). 
Это логично, но мне нужно выводить значения в jTextArea в режиме реального времени, т.е. как только они появляются.

Как это реализовать? Буду благодарен за помощь, либо за ссылку на толковый материал по этому вопросу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте обернуть вызов вашего метода из класса B в поток. К примеру:

```
 /**
 * Метод, в котором выполняются все изменения area
 *
 * @param area элемент
 */
public void dosomething(final JTextArea area) {
    //Создаем поток
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        /**
         * Переопределяем метод run, который и выполняется пр запуске потока
         */
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //Добавляем текст "One"
                area.append("One");
                //Задержка текущего потока 2 млс, чтобы не сразу появился сле.текст
                Thread.sleep(2000L);
                //Добавляем текст "Two"
                area.append("Two");
                //Задержка текущего потока 2 млс, чтобы не сразу появился сле.текст
                Thread.sleep(2000L);
                //Добавляем текст "Three"
                area.append("Three");
                //Задержка текущего потока 2 млс, чтобы не сразу появился сле.текст
                Thread.sleep(2000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                //Если что-то произошло при задержке(Thread.sleep) пишем в консоль
                Logger.getLogger(B.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }).start();//Непосредственно запуск потока 

}
```

Ну и вызов по кнопке, соответственно:

```
new B().dosomething(jTextArea1);
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, буду использовать этот способ. Я новичок в Java, могли бы Вы пожалуйста добавить в код комментарии, а то не очень понимаю как он работает...

Comment: Даже не знаю, что подписать( Что именно не понятно? Если как работает - то тут все просто: ваше приложение выполняется в потоке. По умолчанию. Вы просто этого не видите. А мы что сделали? Верно. Запустили параллельный поток, в который передали выполнение функций. Т.е. вы работаете в основном потоке. Запустили параллельный в "фоновом" режиме и продолжаете работать в основном. А тот, параллельный, работает сам-по себе уже. И не мешает вам)

Comment: Все понял уже, спасибо большое!

Comment: не за что) Комменты добавил